# On degenerate linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is it true that if in $$AX=0$$ where $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix over field $\Bbb K$ and $X$ is a length $n$ vector of variables if $rank(A)=n-1$ we will have an unique solution up to constant factors?

How do you solve for such a solution (assume $XX'=r\in\Bbb N$)?

Comment: Yes, in this case it's true, because $\text{rank}(A) = n-1 \Leftrightarrow \text{dim}(\text{Ker} (A) ) = 1$

Comment: how do you solve? Assume $XX'=r$.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking for the [null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of $A$.

A standard way to find a basis for the null space is to take the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition):

$$ U \Sigma V^* = A $$

where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix containing what is known as the singular values.

- The number of non-zero singular values give you the rank of matrix A.
- The number of zero singular values gives you the dimension of the null space.
- Columns of $V$ associated with zero singular values form a basis for the null space of A.

Note: this is how many numerical linear algebra systems (eg. Matlab, numpy) calculate rank and null space.

Comment: I am seeking $X$.

Comment: @Turbo In what context? Is this a homework problem where you have a specific matrix A?

Comment: no I forgot my linear algebra. I am trying to recollect a good procedure in these situations.

Comment: If you're doing something by hand for a small matrix, you'd just find the solutions to the system $Ax=0$ by hand. If you're doing this for a large matrix on computer, you'd take the singular variable decomposition. Typically, svd routines put zero singular values last in the $\Sigma$ matrix and what you're calling $x$ would be the final column of my matrix $V$. If the null space were two dimensional, it would be the final 2 columns etc...

Comment: that is all I wanted to know and that seems right in retrospective. However what if I replace $\Bbb K$ with a ring $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Works great for real numbers. I'd read up on SVD, it's an intuitive way to understand what matrix multiplication does: rotate, scale then rotate. I'm honestly not super well versed in the abstract concepts of rings etc...